# Firebase notification PHP script

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm testing firebase notification since my old project was integrated to GCM, but now I'm also using firebase database.

I'm trying to execute a php script in order to send notification to one of my device. I'm able to obtain the `TokenID` and also I'm able to send notifications to this token from the Firebase Console, but when I use the PHP script, I have the following error:

> Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.

Here is my script:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key = "AAAXXXXXX";
$key =  "c43xxxxxxxxx";


$headers = array (
    'Authorization: key =' . server_key,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
);

$fields = array('to'=>$key,
            'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message));

$payload = json_encode($fields);

$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 

$result = curl_exec($curl_session);
curl_close($curl_session);

echo $result;
```

I'm getting the api key from:

```
Firebase console > gear icon > proyect configuration > Cloud messaging
```

Comment: How do we spell "authorization?"

Comment: And what is the sigil for a variable in PHP?

Comment: yes "Autorization was wrong", i changed to "Authorization" and now i'm receiving this error /////Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.

Comment: Are you using the Server key or the Legacy Server key?

Comment: The Server key, i tried both and is the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = array (
'Authorization: key =' . server_key,
'Content-Type:application/json'
```

);

you should make the server_key a variable like $server_key